# Name is not defined. learn python hard way ex48

Tags: python

I retyped code from the book learn python hard way ex48 and i get error name 'parse_subj' is not defined. I googled regular solutions for this type of mistake but it didn't he

```
user_sentence = [('verb', 'run'), ('direction', 'north')]
class Sentence(object):

    def __init_(self, subj, verb, obj):
        self.subject = subj[1]
        self.verb = verb[1]
        self.object = obj[1]


    def peek(word_list):
        if word_list:
            word = word_list[0]
            return word
        else:
            return None
    #took the word and get out from list - if it is expecting type return word, if not - None
    def match(word_list, expecting):
        if word_list:
            word = word_list.pop(0)
            if word[0] == expecting:
                return word
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return None

    def skip(word_list, word_type):
        while peek(word_list) == word_type:
            match(word_list, word_type)

    def parse_verb(word_list):
        skip(word_list, 'stop_words')
        next_word = peek(word_list)

        if next_word == 'verb':
            return match(word_list, 'verb')
        else:
            raise ParserError('Expected a verb')

    def parse_obj(word_list):
        skip(word_list, 'stop_words')
        next_word = peek(word_list)

        if next_word == 'nouns':
            return match(word_list, 'nouns')
        elif next_word == 'direction':
            return match(word_list, 'direction')
        else:
            raise ParserError('Expected an obj')

    def parse_subj(word_list):
        skip(word_list, 'stop_words')
        next_word = peek(word_list)

        if next_word == 'pron':
            return match(word_list, 'pron')
        elif next_word == 'verb':
            return ('noun', 'player')
        else:
            raise ParserError('Expected an subj')

    def parse_sentence(word_list):
        subj = parse_subj(word_list)
        verb = parse_verb(word_list)
        obj = parse_obj(word_list)
        return Sentence(subj, verb, obj)

example = Sentence.parse_sentence(user_sentence)
print(example)
```

I tried to play with self and invoking Sentence class in another variable but it didn't work. I even copypasted code from pdf book and it didn't work anyway

Comment: You need to recheck the code you've copied from. If those functions are supposed to be class methods, they should all have `self` as the first parameter, and your call to `parse_subj(word_list)` should actually be `self.parse_subj(word_list)`. Although that's not the only issue with the code.

Comment: It turned out that in original code all functions were outside of class Sentence. This is why all proposed solutions to fix my code pointed at the necessity of self argument

Answer (score 1):

In Python code, there is what is known as the Global scope. That refers to all functions and variables that are not inside any class or any function.

When you simply say `parse_subj`, the interpreter will look for that method in the Global scope. But your method is actually inside the class `Sentence`. You need to explicitly tell the interpreter that `parse_subj` is inside the `Sentence` class and not in the Global scope. You do that either by saying `self.parse_subj`, where `self` is the first parameter of the `parse_subj` method representing an instance of class `Sentence` that you've created. Either that, or you use what is known as an unbounded call, where you explicitly say `Sentence.parse_subj` to tell the interpreter where the method is found.

I don't advise the second approach, but it looks like the logical road since none of your class methods even have the `self` parameter, excepter for the initializer at the top. You would need to go through your entire code adding `Sentence.` before every call to a method in the `Sentence` class.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, word_list is not a list as you intended it to be in most of your methods it is the instance `example`

Second, since the methods that you are trying to call are a part of that instance this is how you are supposed to call them: `self.word_list` and here is how your parameters should be: `self, word_list` in the right order

Third,
instead of `example = Sentence.parse_sentence(user_sentence)`
do

```
example = Sentence("example_subj", "example_verb", "example_obj")
example.parse_sentence(user_sentence)
```

after all, here is the final code:

```py
user_sentence = [('verb', 'run'), ('direction', 'north')]
class Sentence(object):

    def __init_(self, subj, verb, obj):
        self.subject = subj[1]
        self.verb = verb[1]
        self.object = obj[1]


    def peek(self, word_list):
        if word_list:
            word = word_list[0]
            return word
        else:
            return None
    #took the word and get out from list - if it is expecting type return word, if not - None
    def match(self, word_list, expecting):
        if word_list:
            word = word_list.pop(0)
            if word[0] == expecting:
                return word
            else:
                return None
        else:
            return None

    def skip(self, word_list, word_type):
        while self.peek(word_list) == word_type:
            self.match(word_list, word_type)

    def parse_verb(self, word_list):
        self.skip(word_list, 'stop_words')
        next_word = self.peek(word_list)

        if next_word == 'verb':
            return self.match(word_list, 'verb')
        else:
            raise ParserError('Expected a verb')

    def parse_obj(self, word_list):
        self.skip(word_list, 'stop_words')
        next_word = self.peek(word_list)

        if next_word == 'nouns':
            return match(word_list, 'nouns')
        elif next_word == 'direction':
            return self.match(word_list, 'direction')
        else:
            raise ParserError('Expected an obj')

    def parse_subj(self, word_list):
        self.skip(word_list, 'stop_words')
        next_word = self.peek(word_list)

        if next_word == 'pron':
            return self.match(word_list, 'pron')
        elif next_word == 'verb':
            return ('noun', 'player')
        else:
            raise ParserError('Expected an subj')

    def parse_sentence(self, word_list):
        subj = self.parse_subj(word_list)
        verb = self.parse_verb(word_list)
        obj = self.parse_obj(word_list)
        return Sentence(subj, verb, obj)

example = Sentence.parse_sentence(user_sentence)
print(example)
```

Answer (score 1):

A quick answer to your question is that when accessing the method such as `parse_subj` inside a class, you have to call it depending on its method type e.g. if it is an instance method, then you should define an instance of the class first before accessing that method, wherein that method should have been written to accept a `self` (refers to the object instance) as the first argument.

For me, the actual answer to your question is skip that Sentence class for now as it is highly complicated. It is like learning how to multiply without understanding how addition works. You have to understand how this 3 type of methods within a class work:

1. Static method - decorated by `@staticmethod`, can be called using the class itself or a class instance
2. Class method - decorated by `@classmethod`, accepts `cls` as first argument where cls refers to the class itself, can be called using the class itself or a class instance
3. Instance method - no decorator, accepts `self` as first argument where self refers to a class object, **can only be called using a class instance**

You might be interested with this code below which just prints text.

```
class Sample:
    outer_var = "my outer var"

    def __init__(self, var):
        print(f"__init__ var = {var}")
        self.inner_var = var

    @staticmethod
    def this_is_static_method(var3):
        print("==========")
        print(f"this_is_static_method")

        try: print(f"\tSample.outer_var = {Sample.outer_var}")
        except Exception: print("\tERROR!!! Cannot access Sample.outer_var")

        try: print(f"\tSample.inner_var = {Sample.inner_var}")
        except Exception: print("\tERROR!!! Cannot access Sample.inner_var")

        print(f"\tvar3 {var3}")

    @classmethod
    def this_is_class_method(cls, var3):
        print("==========")
        print(f"this_is_class_method type(cls) {type(cls)} cls {cls}")

        try: print(f"\tcls.outer_var = {cls.outer_var}")
        except Exception: print("\tERROR!!! Cannot access cls.outer_var")

        try: print(f"\tcls.inner_var = {cls.inner_var}")
        except Exception: print("\tERROR!!! Cannot access cls.inner_var")

        print(f"\tvar3 {var3}")
        return cls(var3)

    def this_is_instance_method(self, var3):
        print("==========")
        print(f"this_is_instance_method type(self) {type(self)} self {self}")

        try: print(f"\tself.outer_var = {self.outer_var}")
        except Exception: print("\tERROR!!! Cannot access self.outer_var")

        try: print(f"\tself.inner_var = {self.inner_var}")
        except Exception: print("\tERROR!!! Cannot access self.inner_var")

        print(f"\tvar3 {var3}")

print("\n\nUSING THE CLASS DIRECTLY\n\n")

Sample.this_is_static_method(111)
Sample.this_is_class_method(222)
try: Sample.this_is_instance_method(333)
except Exception: print("==========\nERROR!!! Cannot access Sample.this_is_instance_method")

print("\n\nUSING AN INSTANCE OBJECT\n\n")

sample_instance = Sample(444)
sample_instance.this_is_static_method(555)
sample_instance.this_is_class_method(666)
sample_instance.this_is_instance_method(777)
```

Output:

```
USING THE CLASS DIRECTLY


==========
this_is_static_method
    Sample.outer_var = my outer var
    ERROR!!! Cannot access Sample.inner_var
    var3 111
==========
this_is_class_method type(cls) <class 'type'> cls <class '__main__.Sample'>
    cls.outer_var = my outer var
    ERROR!!! Cannot access cls.inner_var
    var3 222
__init__ var = 222
==========
ERROR!!! Cannot access Sample.this_is_instance_method


USING AN INSTANCE OBJECT


__init__ var = 444
==========
this_is_static_method
    Sample.outer_var = my outer var
    ERROR!!! Cannot access Sample.inner_var
    var3 555
==========
this_is_class_method type(cls) <class 'type'> cls <class '__main__.Sample'>
    cls.outer_var = my outer var
    ERROR!!! Cannot access cls.inner_var
    var3 666
__init__ var = 666
==========
this_is_instance_method type(self) <class '__main__.Sample'> self <__main__.Sample object at 0x1551aff90730>
    self.outer_var = my outer var
    self.inner_var = 444
    var3 777
```